# How to switch between background and main threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, user-interface

I've never used background threads before. I have a time consuming computation currently running on the main thread which appends the data output to a TERecord. My workflow essentially goes:

run long process…
update GUI…
run long process…
update GUI…
and so on.

At several places where the code produces (string) output I update the UI by calling my 'addToRecord' method shown here:

```
-(void)addToRecord:(NSString*)passedStr:(BOOL)updateUI
 {
    NSRange endRange;
    // add the passed text...
    endRange.location = [[theOutputView textStorage] length];
    endRange.length = 0;
    [theOutputView replaceCharactersInRange:endRange withString:passedStr];

if(updateUI) // immediate GUI update needed...
    {
    // scroll window contents to BOTTOM of page...
    endRange = NSMakeRange([[theOutputView string] length],0);
    [theOutputView scrollRangeToVisible:endRange];

    [theOutputView display];
    }
}
```

While it does the job, my entire UI remains unresponsive until the process completes, of course. I know I should be doing the heavy lifting on a background thread which I've never used before. I've figured out part of the problem in creating a background thread like below:

```
-(IBAction)readUserInput:(id)sender
{   
// irrelevant code snipped for brevity
if([self checkForErrors] == NO)
    {
    [runButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(runWorkThread)     withObject:nil];
    }
}

-(void)runWorkThread
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    [self runLongProcess];
[pool drain];
}
```

but i just don't understand how to call the main thread every time the code encounters my 'addToRecord' method, then how to return control to the background thread?
Another possibility might be to remove the updateUI  code from my 'addToRecord' method and just have have the main thread calling this code every second or so on a timer?

Any advice and sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, just want to clarify with you about your problem, do you want after `runLongProcess` finished, you want to populate something or notify to call `-(void)addToRecord:(NSString*)passedStr:(BOOL)updateUI` on the main thread?

Comment: @HSG. When I ran the long process on the main thread, it called  'addToRecord' about a dozen times before the process ended. Each time this would draw additional text to the NSTextView AND update the UI in a continuous scrolling action. I'd like to remove the 'updateUI' portion of this method from my background thread, leaving it to just append additional text to the TERecord and somehow get the main thread to update the UI and display it. If I can't update the UI at least 2-3 times while the background process runs (for a few minutes) the blank textview makes it look like the app has stalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `performSelectorInBackground` you can use the **Dispatch** framework (also called GCD), which is the preferred way of handling concurrent work. The Dispatch already has a pool of background threads set up that you can use. To switch thread you call `dispatch_async()` like this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        // :
        // Do your background work here
        // :
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // :
            // Now you are back in the main thread
            // :
        });
    });
```

The first parameter is the queue identifier which is supplied to you by either `dispatch_get_global_queue()` which returns one of the "worker" queues, or `dispatch_get_main_queue()` which returns the main queue. The last parameter is a code block that is executed on the selected queue.

When requesting a concurrent queue using `dispatch_get_global_queue()` you specify a *Quality of Service*, which determines the priority your code will have in relation to other work. See the documentation for more information and possible values.

[Read more on the Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's now working just how I wanted (and GCD does seem simpler to use with no pools to drain etc.).